# Magento duplicates SKU in file export by DataFlow Export

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I use the DataFlow Import/Export for updating product information. But now I am getting duplicates SKU in file results when I try to export product

Can anyone help me ?

Thank you

Comment: DUPLICATE => http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74380/dataflow-export-duplicate-skus-in-sku-field

Answer (score 0):

When you update to Magento 1.9.2.X you will have this problem. If u use the app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Parser/Products.php from a older version of magento it will fix your problem.

You can try using this link, its a temporary fix that uses a older Products.php file:

https://github.com/baconl/Magento-1.9.2.1-duplicate-sku-fix

Keep in mind, this is a temporary fix until the magento core team fixes it in the next version of Magento.